# Apache not start , php

Tags: apache

I can't start apache2 with error
"Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

So, when i check "systemctl status apache2.service"

I check : `apache2ctl configtest`

have error :
"mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/run/apache2': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lock/apache2.G6bcI3GyMQ': Operation not permitted
"
Please help me

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/872162/couldnt-start-apache2-server

Comment: Check the apache2 process privilege. You may check by starting with sudo.

Comment: i seen it, so it not fix success

Comment: when systemctl status apache2.service then
/etc/init.d/apache2: 57: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars

Answer (score 0):

Things to check

- do you have another apache instance running?

`ps aux | grep apache2`

to check if you have and

```
pkill -9 apache
```

and start apache again.

if not check with ...

```
ls -l /var/lock/apache2.26wFR2Eely
```

the username and group of the file. The username and group need to match what you set apache up with. If not remove this file and start apache again.

sources: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/872162/couldnt-start-apache2-server
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/129920